# Changes not reflecting on flutter web deploy after firebase project owner changed

Tags: flutter, firebase-hosting, flutter-web

Using flutter web I created a web app that can connect to firestore and deployed using firebase hosting. Everything works fine until I change the owner from myself to another. I can still use firebase deploy using the other(2nd) account, but the changes are not reflecting when opening the app url. Is there any need for additional configuration or its a bug? Thanks for any answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to fix by doing a hard cache reset on Chrome, by using the following key
combination: `ctrl + shift + r`.

Or, you can delete the `build/web` folder and build your project for web again.

Comment: It actually worked but in my case I have to delete the the ''build/web' then flutter build web again and to clear all cache on the browsers

Comment: If it helped you please mark the answer as correct.

Comment: It does help me however I think that the most vital steps that has been done was deleting build/web then doing build again, since the issue was also present on other device browser. To avoid confusion for future viewer I would appreciate it you could add that step then I will mark this as accepted

Comment: I have added the that extra step to the answer

Answer (score 0):

In your flutter project Delete web platform and build/web folders

open command prompt and run

> flutter create . --platforms web

this will create web folder again run

again build for web

> flutter build web

to run web app locally you need to install lite-server run

> npm install -g lite-server

after successful install from your project directory run

> cd build/web && lite-server

It will run you web app locally on your machine So before deploying to the firebase hosting do some more changes in `firebase.json` and `index.html` file.
[for more help refer article](https://medium.com/@ankitrajdwivedi/how-to-deploy-flutter-web-app-to-firebase-hosting-f0ac3d59ecfe)
[flutter app not updating in firebase hosting](https://medium.com/@ankitrajdwivedi/flutter-web-app-b4b5487d72c)

After that in your project directory do the changes in file `firebase.json` :

```
"hosting": {
"site" : "statepcs3",
"public": "build/web",
"ignore": [
  "firebase.json",
  "**/.*",
  "**/node_modules/**"
],
"headers": [

  {
    "source": "**",
    "headers": [
      {
        "key": "Cache-Control",
        "value": "no-cache"
      }
    ]
  }

]
}
```

then deploy again in firebase hosting and it will work.

Answer (score 0):

First build:

```
flutter build web
```

Then deploy:

```
firebase deploy
```