# Firebase only hosts previous version of Flutter web app

Tags: firebase, flutter

I hosted my web application through Firebase using Flutter. Initially, it was absolutely fine but I realised there was a small error so changed it an redeployed it. However, when I ran `flutter deploy` it didn't change on the website. I thought that I might have to wait a while for the change to happen but I waited 5 hours and it still hasn't updated. I then tried a few more times, deleting different cache files but nothing worked. I then deleted the Firebase project all together and made a completely new one. I deleted the `.firebaserc` and `firebase.json` files. However, on the new website, it is still showing the old version of the website. I don't understand how that could be possible but any help would be really appreciated!

Comment: It’s a caching issue, check out this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65875137/13646430

Comment: hi @Andrej thanks, unfortunately its not. As I mentioned I deleted cache files and also deleted the cache on chrome. I have had the caching issue a few times so I know that its definitely not that. Thank you very much though!

Comment: Visit your site from an incognito tab and validate. Also make sure you didn't forget to run `flutter build web` before firebase deploy.

Comment: Try it on the site, press CTRL + SHIFT + R

Comment: @HuthaifaMuayyad thank you so much, I was following a tutorial and it didn't include the ```flutter build web``` but that worked perfectly! Thank you

Comment: Awesome, I'll add it an answer to your post, please consider marking it as an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Visit your site from an incognito tab and validate. Also make sure you didn't forget to run `flutter build web` before firebase deploy.

Comment: any other solution ? I am facing the same issues right now. we cant ask our users to use our web app on the incoginito mode